# Which MIME types are used for HTML/web pages

Tags: html, http-headers, mime-types, mime

Which MIME types are used for web pages (no matter if HTML/XHTML/HTML5, etc.)?

I just need a list of MIME types, which are used for serving browsers with web pages and not files (PDF, Word, images, ZIP archives, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- HTML: `text/html`
- MHTML: `multipart/related`
- XHTML: `application/xhtml+xml`
- CSS: `text/css`
- JavaScript: `application/javascript`
- JSON: `application/json`
- Internet Explorer's behavior (*.htc*): `text/x-component`

Comment: I would also include multipart/related for MHTML files, although I suspect it could be used for other things too.